# Ada: Reading From File Issue

Tags: ada

So I am having to read relations from a text file to perform a topological sort on them. The problem is that the data in the relations is heterogeneous. There are about 3 different enumeration data types, and there is also integers and floats in the mix. When reading this data from the file, from my understanding, it is read and stored as a String until you perform an Unchecked_Conversion. Ultimately my question is, if I were to read any text file with an arbitrary mix of these types, would I need to scan each one I come across to see what type it is before converting it? Like, would I have to scan every element checking for a period, ".", to determine whether to convert it to an integer or a float? Thanks!

UPDATED:
The data in each file is going to be plain text generated by me, not another program. As far as structure and order, I will show what data sets I have to process, then explain how I plan to put them in a file. So here are the data sets I need to process (each in a separate file):

```
Mary < Tom, Tom < Bob, Tom < Sam, Joe < Sam, Sam < Betty, and Mary < Sam, Bob < Betty, Joe < Betty

1<2, 1<3, 2<3, 4<1, 3<8, 8<9, 8<2, 4<2, 4<5, 6<4, 5<7, 2<7, 7<9, 9<8, 9<6, 2<7, 4<2, 9<8

(Ford, 2) < (Apple, 30.0), (Joe, sorcerer) < (orange, 56.2), (apple, 30.0) < (banana, 45.0), ... , (Bennett, warrior) < (Ford, 2)
```

These are the 3 basic ones: Strings that are names, integers, and Objects. There are 3 different Objects: CAR(type, numDoors), FOOD(type, numCalories), PERSON(name, class). I plan to put all of the information in the file sequentially line by line. In this way, I can process each line two by two, since the relations come in pairs. For the Objects though, every 4 lines will be one relation, and I will need to collect each line in pairs to initialize the fields of the Object. (Last time I said the relations were of mixed types. This was a mistake on me, for I did not understand that some data were Object fields.) In doing this, I will need to instantiate a Generic passing the name of the file I am reading from and processing. For the Strings and integers, I can just keep the Strings that are read in how they are, and use the 'Value attribute to convert the integers to integers. My problem is with the Objects. How do you think I should go about reading them in and converting the information? Would I need to scan each one to see what Object it belonged to of the 3? THANKS

Comment: If you don't know anything about the data in the file, then you can't process it computationally.  Try to explain how the data is organised in the file.  Is it plain text or raw data?  What is the structure?  Is there any order?

Comment: It seems that the file content is somewhat known: enumerations, integers, and floats. Have these files originally been produced using typical Ada means? E.g, [streams](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ada/8865/files-and-i-o-streams), or maybe using `'Output`?

Comment: Please, at the very least, give us something to work on. A few sample lines would be a start. Also, I’ve edited your tags; the only one relevant to _this_ question is [ada].

Comment: I updated the question, hopefully it makes more sense. @JacobSparreAndersen

Comment: I updated the question, hopefully it makes more sense. @B98

Comment: I updated the question, hopefully it makes more sense. @SimonWright

Comment: Do you know that Ford is a sort of Car, Apple a sort of Food? would (Apple, 30.0) be different from a [larger] (apple, 45.0)? could a new class be introduced by an entry (Osric, gravedigger)? As it stands, you’re going to have to read each Object’s first part to know what to do with the second part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the names of the objects uniquely identify their type, e.g. `Banana` is always a `Fruit` and not naming a state of mind or anything else, say, then use `'Value` on suitable parts of your input lines. Then, alternatively, you *could* also use brute force and the `Ada.Text_IO` packages: whenever the text "BANANA" can be passed to an instance of `Enumeration_IO.Get` for `Fruit`, producing a value in the type `Fruit`, there you are. (Note that `'<'` etc. could also be made literals of an enumeration type, so that you'd use the same method for reading orderings.)

**However**! You'll probably really need a parser or something close to it; I/O of non-standard syntax text is never entirely trivial. E.g. start with one of the pattern matching libraries, such as for regular expressions, to isolate the parts of your text. Another way of finding the parts of your file – since you know them – is to use the string search routines in `Ada.Strings.Fixed`.

However, if you change the syntax of your file to be one of those widely supported, such as JSON, XML, Graphviz notation… then suitable libraries will become available. Catchwords include "serialisation" or "marshalling".

```
<pair type="name">
  <first>Tom</first>
  <second>Sam</second>
</pair>
```

JSON will be shorter, since you can drop self-describing tags and/or type information of XML if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Unchecked_Conversion` is seldom a good idea to convert from `String`.  You will typically use the `'Value` attribute for that.

Comment: `’Value`, not `’Image`

Comment: Thanks!  Correcting the answer.

Comment: Yes you're right, I will be using the 'Value attribute